# What are MUP (Multi Uni Processors)?

Tags: scheduler, processor, rtai

Are MUP (Multi Uni Processors) the same as multi-core processors or do they have separate CPUs inter-wired for communication? I feel AMPs are still different. Can anyone please clarify?
Came across this while reading about RTAI (real time extention to linux) schedulers.. Please check the link and preferrably the first line and relevant last para..
 https://www.rtai.org/userfiles/documentation/magma/html/api/sched_overview.html

Comment: Can you link a URL that uses this term?  The top google hits are actually other things, like normal multi-core CPUs.

Comment: Thanks Peter.. just edited the post

Comment: It might just be a term for how the scheduler treats an SMP machine.  I don't think that description implies that there's any hardware that requires it.  i.e. on SMP hardware, you can run the MUP scheduler or the SMP scheduler.

Comment: MUP is not porcessor; it is term of RTAI scheduler: MUP scheduler. There is definition in 2003 paper of RTAI https://www.rtai.org/userfiles/documentation/documents/motioncontrol2003.pdf "The MUP scheduler instead imposes that any task is assigned to a specific CPU from its very creation and can achieve better  performances because it can exploit memory caching more efficiently."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is RTAI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTAI, https://www.rtai.org/) specific term to specify one of three scheduler kinds. They were defined in 2003 paper https://www.rtai.org/userfiles/documentation/documents/motioncontrol2003.pdf

"Linux Real Time Application Interface (RTAI) in low cost high performance motion control"

> RTAI makes available three schedulers: Uniprocessor (UP), optimised for uniprocessor machines; Symmetric Multi Processors (SMP) and Multi UniProcessor (MUP) for symmetric multiprocessors applications. The SMP scheduler affords the best compromise between flexibility and efficiency in kernel space applications using RTAI proper kernel tasks, as it can schedule any ready task on any CPU, while allowing to selectively impose selected tasks to run on a specific CPU or CPUs cluster. The MUP scheduler instead imposes that any task is assigned to a specific CPU from its very creation and can achieve better performances because it can exploit memory caching more efficiently. ...
>    There is no restriction in the use of any scheduler, real time tasks can interact without any constraint, irrespective of what CPU they are running on. SMP and MUP schedulers can be used also with uniprocessors.

So, "UP" scheduler can use only single core of processor. "SMP" scheduler can use multiple cores (or CPUs clusters - physical processors in NUMA) to plan task on them, and can remap task from one core to other. And "MUP" scheduler can use multiple cores, but will not move tasks from one core to another. Tasks will always have their data in nearest cache with MUP, unlike "SMP" when the task may be moved away from its cached data.

Some resources are not shared in MUP scheduler, which can be useful for combining several realtime tasks on one machine. MUP uses one timer per CPU (and SMP have common timer?):

> It is also important to note that the MUP scheduler uses independent per CPU timers and each of them can run independently from any other, so that timers
>   mode of operation can be freely assigned, e.g. there can be periodic and oneshot timers and periodic timers need not to run at the same period.

www.cs.ucf.edu/~lboloni/Teaching/EEL6897_2007/presentations/ZubairIlhan_RTAI.ppt

> SMP&MUP Scheduler
>
> - SMP can schedule tasks to more than one CPU. Different degrees of additional services can be dealt with on a specific CPU.
> - SMP scheduler remains a priority driven scheduler.
> - MUP scheduler views a multiprocessor machine *as a collection of many uniprocessors*. Each CPU can have its timer programmed differently.
> - With MPU, a CPU can run in periodic mode while another running in one-shot mode.

Comment: Book "Embedded Linux System Design and Development" (2005) https://books.google.com/books?id=yORMBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA254&lpg=PA254&dq=rtai+smp+mup lists SMP as "Intended for SMP machines" and MUP as  "Intended for multiprocessor non-SMP machines"; but I don't know any real machine without cache coherence between processors capable of running single real image of Linux kernel...

Comment: Are there other things besides lack of cache-coherency that could make a multi-processor system non-SMP?  A big.LITTLE system isn't symmetric in performance, but I think most people would still call it an SMP.  I guess a multi-CPU system where one CPU didn't support all the same instruction-set extensions would qualify as non-SMP.  (Because it matters which core a process runs on.)

Comment: Peter Cordes, NUMA (multi-socket AMD/Intel is here) is not symmetric (SMP ~= UMA), but still tightly [coupled multiprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessing#Processor_coupling), usually cache coherent ccNUMA; with all RAM memory visible to every core (accessible with plain load/store commands) and with single OS image. Loosely coupled multiprocessor system is cluster and shares network. There are lot of [AMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_multiprocessing): CPU+GPGPU, APU, Xeon + Phi, some have shared memory other have separate; but usually 1 OS on CPU (2 OS with Phi).